# SQL server connection trouble in network but not in local

Tags: sql-server-2005, networking, jdbc, local

for the first time that I would work with SQL SERVER 2005, the jdbc connection doesn't work in the network I searched and have done thousand of things that doesn't work, i also want to precise that i already had worked with other DBMS, so here is the problem:
when i try to connect by jdbc from the machine where sql server is installed everything work just fine, but when i try from a different machine, the jdbc is unable to create the connection, i already checked that TCP/IP communication is enabled that the port (not dynamically assigned) is 1433 and i even tried with different ports, i also tried with the same driver and different driver, i checked that i was able to communicate with the http server (who is installed in the machine where SQL server is installed) and it works  but that jdbc connection can't, i tried thousand of things until i forgot some of them, 
someone please help

Comment: can you print the error message?

Comment: Try using telnet from the client  machine (open a command prompt, type "telnet TARGETMACHINENAME 1433"). If you can get a connection, then the problem is your JDBC settings. If you can't get a connection, look at the firewall on your SQL server box.

Comment: it's ok it was the firewall Sorry

Answer (score 0):

Is portforwarding enabled? You have to configure your router.